# Creating library project in Android with MapActivity and using that in another project?

Tags: android, mapactivity

I have created a project as library that uses MapActivity but when it is referenced in another project it cannot link with that project. But if the same project is used with only Activity then everything works properly. The project is linked properly and the activity of the library gets called from other project.

The error that shows up in the logcat is Unable to resolve superclass of packagename/SampleLibActivity; (13)

I really do not understand the reason of error only when extending with MapActivity. Are there any limitations with creating library project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a silly mistake of not including uses-library inside application tag.

Hope this helps out someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Have add the key generated from google maps in the new project?

Comment: Yes. The layout file is in both the projects i.e. in library project and the other project with the key specified in the layout file itself.